# $\mathbb{C}$ is a $\mathbb{R}$ vector-space: problems with field embedding

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

We define $\mathbb{C}$ to be the triple $(\mathbb{R}^2,+,\cdot)$ where $+$ is the standard componentwise addition and $\cdot$ is defined by 
$$(x_1,y_1) \cdot (x_2,y_2) := (x_1x_2 - y_1y_2, x_1y_2 + y_1x_2)$$

We have a field embedding $\mathbb{R} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $x \mapsto (x,0)$. Therefore we can "identify" the real number $x$ with $(x,0)$.

> $\mathbb{C}$ is a $\mathbb{R}$ vector space.

I mean the vector addition is simply given by addition in $\mathbb{C}$. However, we have to define scalar multiplication by elements of $\mathbb{R}$. I mean it is obvious that we define $\cdot : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ by $\cdot(\lambda,z) = \lambda z$ where the righthandside means multiplication in $\mathbb{C}$. Now my question is, to be completely rigorous, we should define the scalar multiplication by $$\cdot(\lambda,z) = \iota(\lambda)z$$ where $\iota$ is the embedding of $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{C}$. But this is somehow never done, instead we simply consider the scalar multiplication $\cdot: \iota(\mathbb{R}) \times \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, I think.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I try to formulate it more properly, but I think it is "hard". Maybe we start with how is scalar multiplication defined on the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Yes, this is the way mathematicians use "identify": we have a bijection from the reals themselves and the reals as a subset of the complex numbers, and instead of writing this bijection every time we pretend that they are literally the same set. This should not cause any problems until you dive very deep into foundations, where you want to be precise about these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem here. For any $\lambda\in\Bbb R$ and $(x,y)\in\Bbb C$, we have

$$\iota(\lambda)\cdot(x,y)=(\lambda,0)\cdot(x,y)=(\lambda x,\lambda y)=\lambda(x,y),$$

so the "rigorous" way of defining the scalar multiplication agrees with the "naive" way.

Also, I may be misunderstanding your question so let me know if that's the case.

Comment: Thanks. I think my question is a bit vague, indeed. I think my main confusion is, that we simply use $\mathbb{R}$ and $\iota(\mathbb{R})$ interchangeably. But your answer is fine.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek that's a common occurrence you'll see throughout a lot of mathematics if you keep studying, the "abuse of notation". If we were to carefully spell out every detail with the "proper" notation, math would be incredibly difficult to read. It's clear (for instance, from my original response) that no mistakes will arise from identifying $\Bbb R$ with $\iota(\Bbb R)$, as the two really are isomorphic fields and the embedding of $\iota(\Bbb R)$ into $\Bbb C$ here matches the embedding of $\Bbb R$ into the usual way of thinking about $\Bbb C$ (i.e. elements of the form $a+bi$).

Comment: Thanks a lot again. Yes, I understand this. It would be terribly difficult otherwise. But my way of thinking is usually that I prove something like this rigorously the first time and then use the abuse of notation to be completely sure that it works. But I thinkt that I am now able to do this.